# Google OAuth 2.0 for asp.net core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, google-api-dotnet-client

I want to add Google calendar integration to my asp.net core web application. Once authorised for a user, the app will send updates to the user's calendar in the future.

The [google api docs](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-aspnet-mvc) show how to use a `FlowMetaData` and a custom `IDataStore` in an asp.net MVC app to simplify the oauth dance and subsequent storage of tokens for a user, which looks spot on for what I need, but it's not core-compatible.

Is there a similar way to do this using asp.net core?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's currently no fully supported way to do this.

The following PRs show two different approaches that may be useful:

- https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/pull/1163
- https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/pull/1109

Note that neither are merged, and I know that #1163 is currently unfinished.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I'm trying to work out how to do this in a core web app. I've got as far as managing to get an access token and refresh token from google, so I can store the refresh token for my user. But is there a way to use that refresh token with the google API libs?

Comment: Neither are merged. We are still planning to do some work on this, but we don't have a fixed timescale for the work.